# How to make the installation always run silently?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to start the silent installation for my application without Next buttons in the installation wizard process. Please any one help me.

[image]

Comment: For a similar question with different answers, see [Run installation using Inno Setup silently without any Next button or Install button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42089779/850848)

Answer (score 25):

Proper way to run the setup in silent mode is, and always be executing it with [`/SILENT`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm#SILENT) command line parameter. For instance this way:

```
setup.exe /SILENT
```

After we clarified your requirement in comments I see, that you actually want to build a setup, which will run in silent mode without the mentioned command line parameter. Currently, there's no built-in way to tell the compiler, that you want to build a silent setup, so we need to workaround this by re-running  the setup with the [`/SILENT`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm#SILENT) command line parameter when the setup is being initialized.

The following script shows this workaround:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
type
  HINSTANCE = THandle;

function ShellExecute(hwnd: HWND; lpOperation: string; lpFile: string;
  lpParameters: string; lpDirectory: string; nShowCmd: Integer): HINSTANCE;
  external 'ShellExecute{#AW}@shell32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  // if this instance of the setup is not silent which is by running
  // setup binary without /SILENT parameter, stop the initialization
  Result := WizardSilent;
  // if this instance is not silent, then...
  if not Result then
  begin
    // re-run the setup with /SILENT parameter; because executing of
    // the setup loader is not possible with ShellExec function, we
    // need to use a WinAPI workaround
    if ShellExecute(0, '', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), '/SILENT', '',
      SW_SHOW) <= 32
    then
      // if re-running this setup to silent mode failed, let's allow
      // this non-silent setup to be run
      Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Miral, being marked as malware is just what the requirement deserves.

Comment: @TLama. Great script! I've been wondering how it is possible to do this.

Comment: Is this the only way to do this with InnoSetup 6.2.1? Is there an easier way to do a silent install?