# Possibly to run silent and verysilent from within the application

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup, silent-installer

Is it possible to run the silent and verysilent option from within the inno setup application.That is as soon as I clicked the exe it will run with verysilent option (no need to provide it in the command prompt)
I have figured out the temporary way of putting the command with verysilent option in the batch script and clicking the batch script :) !

Comment: Aren't you looking for [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577388/960757) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Bad Form™ make a "covert" installer. From [Inno's FAQ](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#silent):

> **Is it possible to do a silent install without using the /SILENT or /VERYSILENT command-line parameters?**
>   No, nor is such a feature planned (it would be abused). If it is your intention to keep user interaction to a minimum, use the Disable* [Setup] section directives.

This would only matter if you are actually building the installer. If you're just trying to install the application, the only sensible thing to do is use the [command-line flags](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm) in a batch file (or other scripting language).

Comment: That is officially correct, but [`I did it`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577388/960757) with just Inno Setup Pascal Script ;-)